# PyTouch or TensorFlow version error in Open3D-ML

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pytorch, open3d

I'm currently using Open3D 0.15.2 and would like to use Open3D-ML for object recognition.
However, the error occurs depending on the version of PyTorch or TensorFlow.

error code

```
~$ python3 -c "import open3d.ml.torch as ml3d"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/limlab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/open3d/ml/torch/__init__.py", 
line 39, in <module>
raise Exception('Version mismatch: Open3D needs PyTorch version {}, but '
Exception: Version mismatch: Open3D needs PyTorch version 1.8.*, but version 
1.10.1+cu113 is installed!


~$ python3 -c "import open3d.ml.tf as ml3d"
2022-04-27 18:32:41.971453: I 
tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened 
dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/limlab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/open3d/ml/tf/__init__.py", line 
39, in <module>
raise Exception('Version mismatch: Open3D needs TensorFlow version {}, but'
Exception: Version mismatch: Open3D needs TensorFlow version 2.5.*, but version 2.4.0 
is installed!
```

I’m working with

```
Linux: 20.04
PyTorch: 1.10.1+cu113
TensorFlow: 2.4.0
CUDA: 11.0.228
```

How can I use Open3D-ML without destroying my environment?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with using a separate [python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) for open3d-ml where you install the pytorch version open3d-ml expects.

Not tested, but I mean something along these lines:

```sh
# install pip if it's not already installed
pip install virtualenv
# create a new virtual env for open3d-ml 
# (optionally cd into the dir you want to store this virtual env folder)
python -m virtualenv o3d-ml-env
# activate the virtual environment
source o3d-ml-env\scripts\activate
# install the PyTorch version open3d-ml requires
pip install torch==1.8.1+cu111 torchvision==0.9.1+cu111 torchaudio==0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

There might be a couple of gotchas:

- You currently have PyTorch 1.10.1+**cu113** (CUDA 11.3) but CUDA: 11.0.228: hopefully that still works ?
- You can have multiple versions of CUDA installed AFAIK, as long the display driver is compatible with those CUDA versions (and disk space allows you to)
- If you have PyTorch 1.10.1 installed globally (e.g. `/home/limlab/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/*`) I'm not sure the virtual environment will override it or not. You might want to uninstall it and create a separate pytorch 1.10.1 virtualenvironment for your other torch project that require this version specifically (aren't compatible with 1.8.1)

Unfortunately I can't test with a setup close to yours, but hopefully the notes illustrate the idea of separating virtual environments to be able to handle multiple versions of PyTorch without conflicts